# Use extract node on a webpage that requires secured authentication?

Tags: security, https, node-red, dataflow

I'd like to use node-red in order to extract information from a website. Kinda simple, but the difficulty for me is that you have to login on this website if you want an access to the useful information.

Basically, when I want to send a HTTP request to the web page, I'm redirected in the HTTPS login page. For now I tried to use a first HTTP request node in order to get to the web page. Then I use the msg.responseUrl to get the adress of the login web page. I pass this URL through a new http request node (and the previous header).

There is the problem, I don't know how to tell node-red to use my login information. The authentication is form-based.

I tried to understand how the option "Enable secure (SSL/TLS) connection" of the HTTP request node works but I'm kinda lost with that.
Any idea ?

Comment: You need to show us what you've already tried. Also without understanding how the site you want to access does authentication (HTTP Basic, Form based) it will be very hard to help with this. Also please read the doc on how to ask a good Stack Overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The question isn't specific enough to answer which I guess is as you don't know how that website operates.  If you turn on developer tools in chrome you can sometimes figure out how to access it programmatically.  Might be worth playing with something like Postman or RestClient as well.